# Ansible playbook - does include_role and delegate_to work together

Tags: ansible

Does include_role and delegate_to work together in Ansible 2.9 as I'm trying to execute the following playbook by running a role and delegating it to host 2 (code below)?

**Ansible playbook**

```
- name: top level playbook
  hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true
  ignore_errors: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        playbook_dir: /Users/OneDrive 
        validation_overall: 'pass'
        result: {}
        all_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"

    - name: import hostvars
      include_vars:
        dir: '{{ playbook_dir }}/test_env_vars/hostvars'
        files_matching: '{{ inventory_hostname }}.*'

    - name: initialise required input variables
      set_fact:
        input_interfaces: "{{ e_input_interfaces }}"  

    # delegate role to host2
    - name: "call validate_rtr_state role with host '{{ansible_hostname}}' for hosts in '{{ansible_play_hosts}}'"
      include_role:
        name: validate_rtr_state
        tasks_from: cisco-ios-xr_ping.yml
      apply:
        delegate_to: "{{all_hosts[1]}}"
      loop: "{{ansible_play_hosts}}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: all_hosts[1]
```

**The error msg I receive is as follows:**

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: apply, include_role

The error appears to be in '/home/bbann/Ansible-Networking/ha_failover_top_level_reload.yml': line 46, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    # delegate role to tusredrweca908
    - name: "call validate_rtr_state role with host '{{ansible_hostname}}' for hosts in '{{ansible_play_hosts}}'"
      ^ here
```

We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

```
with_items:
  - {{ foo }}
```

Should be written as:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

Any ideas why this is failing?

Answer (score 6):

Q: ***"ERROR! conflicting action statements: apply, include_role"***

A: The indentation of `apply` is wrong. It's a parameter of the task `include_role`

```yaml
# delegate role to host2
    - name: "call validate_rtr_state role with host '{{ ansible_hostname }}' for hosts in '{{ ansible_play_hosts }}'"
      include_role:
        name: validate_rtr_state
        tasks_from: cisco-ios-xr_ping.yml
        apply:
          delegate_to: "{{ all_hosts[1] }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: all_hosts[1]
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

There are other weirdos:

1. `loop_var` is the name of the 2nd host? i.e. Does the role implement the name of the 2nd host as a variable?
2. Are there 2 hosts in the play both with `connection: local`?
3. Why `apply delegate_to: xy` instead of `delegate_to: xy` the task?

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, what I'm trying to achieve is reboot host 1 in the play and then include_role validate_rtr_state and delegate_to host 2 but it fails even if I use delegate_to: host2 instead of apply delegate_to.

Comment: It's too complex. Split it to one problem per question and make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! Make it minimal, abstract the problem, as simple as possible, please! (For example,  set_fact of `input_interfaces` is irrelevant to the problem.) Help us to help you!

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I've strip the playbook as simple as possible and pasted it below. Basically I'm trying to run a task to include_role called validate_rtr_state and run a ping task from that role and delegate_to run on host2 only.

Comment: Here's the stripped down play -                                                                                                                                                                                - name: top level playbook
  hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  ignore_errors: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        all_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}" 
- name: call validate_rtr_state role and delegate to host2 
      include_role:
        name: validate_rtr_state
        tasks_from: cisco-ios-xr_ping.yml
      delegate_to: "{{all_hosts[1]}}"